# Patents in GeoSpatial software: impact on practices?

Tags: free-software, legal

I've seen on twitter a tweet saying:

> Palantir has done well turning chapters of intro computational
>   geometry, GIS, and ontology textbooks [into patents](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=pts&hl=en&q=inassignee%3a%22Palantir%20Technologies,%20Inc.%22#hl=en&q=inassignee%3a%22Palantir%20Technologies,%20Inc.%22&tbm=pts):

Looking into the results, my main concern is about the patent concerning ["Simplifying a polygon"](https://www.google.com/patents/US8514229?dq=inassignee%3a%22Palantir%20Technologies,%20Inc.%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XBilUv_DNcSI0AXEpIDgCQ&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAQ) (I use polygon simplification with the MapShaper tool or the Douglas Peucker algorithm in PostGIS or GDAL ...)
Do you know the impact of this patent in particular? I have to stop using polygon simplification?

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you name a specific "ontology textbook"?

Comment: Would you be able to use the edit button to revise your question because my understanding is that asking for opinions is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: @whuber Handbook on Ontologies >> http://www.springer.com/business+%26+management/business+information+systems/book/978-3-540-70999-2

Comment: I think you should focus this question on the one specific example that you begin with and remove the last two broad questions from your Question.

Comment: Already changes sentence. Not enough precise? What need to be change here now?